# Error-grub:PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, pci

I have install 16.04 Ubuntu OS beside with Windows 10 on my laptop. When I start my laptop or use `dmesg` command on terminal. I always get this error log

```
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
```

And I have tried adding to the grub `pci=nomsi`, `pci=noaer` and `pcie_aspm=off`. But nothing improve, and I have try editing `/etc/default/grub` file like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text pcie_aspm=off"
```

Before, I have tried to adding for pci=nomsi and pci=noaer parameter in `/etc/default/grub` file like above.
Please help me to solve it!
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am currently experiencing something similar